# Passing a variable from jquery to php

Tags: php, jquery, phpquery

I am trying to pass a variable from jquery to php

My jquery code:

```
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
$.get("as.php",url="http://www.wired.co.uk/news/archive/2013-01/10/chinese-desert-mystery", function(data,status){
$('#lax').html(data);
});
});
</script>
<div id="lax" >
</div>
```

And my "as.php" file is as follows:

```
<?php
include('phpQuery.php');
$file = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, strip_tags(trim($_GET['url'])));  
phpQuery::newDocumentFileHTML($file);
$titleElement = pq('title'); 
$title = $titleElement->html();
echo '<a href="" >' . htmlentities( $title) . '</a><br/>';

foreach(pq('meta') as $li)

  if ((pq($li)->attr('name')=='description')||(pq($li)->attr('name')=='Description')){
   echo '<p>'.pq($li)->attr('content').'</p>';
}
?>
```

I am tryin to pass 'url' variable from jquery code to my "as.php" file , but not able to do so. Where must be I going wrong?

Comment: btw you shouldn't wait for window load, use DOM ready function. `$(document).ready(fn)`

Comment: Do you have error handling in your database code? You should try to return just `$_GET['url']` to see if the problem is in javascript or php.

Comment: My jquery is little bad.. please tell me how it is useful than window load function.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Thnx for the info gdoron.

Comment: @jeroen, I think problem is in my php, am not able to figure out

Answer (score 4):

You need to create an object

```
url="http://www.wired.co.uk/news/archive/2013-01/10/chinese-desert-mystery"
```

Should be:

```
{url :"http://www.wired.co.uk/news/archive/2013-01/10/chinese-desert-mystery"}
```

[**jQuery docs**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Comment: @RobbieDc, My PHP knowledge is about... zero and if you tried that already then your problem is in your PHP code.

Comment: Ok, Thanx for helping in the jquery part

Answer (score 1):

I don't see you opening a database connection, so with the code you posted `$dbc` will be `NULL`.

That causes `mysqli_real_escape_string` to return `NULL` as well.

As you are not doing any database operations, you should get rid of `mysqli_real_escape_string` completely.

Comment: Tried opening db connection, did not work. Any other alternative?

Comment: @Robbie Dc Just remove it, you don't need it.

Comment: removed, now what to do next?

Comment: @Robbie Dc That depends on the problem you are having :-) I would just open as.php in the browser with the required query string and debug line by line.

Comment: My problem is am not able to pass the 'url' variable to php code, do i use  $.ajax instead of $.get ?

Answer (score 0):

in you jquery:

```
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
$.get("as.php",
{url:"http://www.wired.co.uk/news/archive/2013-01/10/chinese-desert-mystery"}, function(data){
$('#lax').html(data);
});
});
</script>
```

in your php try using `$_REQUEST`

```
<?php
include('phpQuery.php');
$file = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, strip_tags(trim($_REQUEST['url'])));  
phpQuery::newDocumentFileHTML($file);
$titleElement = pq('title'); 
$title = $titleElement->html();
echo '<a href="" >' . htmlentities( $title) . '</a><br/>';

foreach(pq('meta') as $li)

  if ((pq($li)->attr('name')=='description')||(pq($li)->attr('name')=='Description')){
   echo '<p>'.pq($li)->attr('content').'</p>';
}
?>
```